# Linq left join with multiple tables

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I am developing web application in .net. I have come across with below scenario.

Below is my first table.

```
perm_levelid  scrn_id  perm_id  perm_read  perm_write
40               1        2         1         1
41               2        2         1         1
42               3        2         1         1
```

Below is my second table.

```
scrn_id   scrn_name   
1         UserProfile
2         Change Password
3         Dashboard
4         Lease request
```

The relation between above two table is scrn_id

The output i am expecting is

```
scrn_id  perm_id  perm_read  perm_write
1           2           1      1
2           2           1      1
3           2           1      1
4           0           0      0
```

I want total 4 rows in the result. scrn_id 1,2,3 matching in both tables so i should retrieve first table perm_read  and perm_write values. Remaining value from 2 nd table also i want to get.

I tried as below.

```
List<screendetails> obj = new List<screendetails>();
obj = (from c in db.rolsp_perm_levelmapping
       join mapdetails in db.rolsp_scrn_screen on c.scrn_id equals mapdetails.scrn_id
       into mapObj
       from wt in mapObj.DefaultIfEmpty()
       where c.perm_id== permisssionID
       select new screendetails {
            scrn_id=c.scrn_id,
            scrn_name= wt.scrn_name,
            Read=c.perm_read,
            Write=c.perm_write
}).ToList();
return obj;
```

Above query does not yields correct result. May i get some help here to fix this? Thank you

Comment: "*does not yields correct result*", could you elaborate on that? What is it currently returning?

Comment: thank you. i am not getting unmatched data of second table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
obj= (from scrn in db.rolsp_scrn_screen
  from rmap in db.rolsp_perm_levelmapping
  .Where(rl=>rl.scrn_id==scrn_id).DefaultIfEmpty() select new screendetails {
                        scrn_id=scrn.scrn_id,
                        scrn_name= scrn.scrn_name,
                        Read=rmap.perm_read,
                        Write=rmap.perm_write
            }).ToList();
```

Try using this... Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you. I am getting total 4 rows of data considering above example. But 4th row returns me true and true but it should be false because 4th row doesnt match with other table.

Comment: Thank you manasa. I changed as this and started working .Where(c=>c.perm_id==permisssionID)
                       .Where(rl => rl.scrn_id ==scrn.scrn_id ).DefaultIfEmpty(). Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not arguing that it doesn't work, but that is one ugly, hard to read snippet of code. Not your fault, it's due to the naming convention( violation)s; but still :)